# Salesforce SOQL for retrieving cases

Tags: python, salesforce

I am using pythons simple-salesforce to fetch information from sf. My requirement is to pul data about **cases** in **queues** set up by my organisation. I am unable to gather information from queues,cause I don’t know how to access them using SOQL,is there any online resource that might help me get there?

Answer (score 0):

You can query queues from the Group object.

```
Select Id from Group where Type = 'Queue'
```

For a specific queue you can use:

```
Select Id from Group where  Type = 'Queue' AND NAME = 'QueueName'
```

You can find all available fields for the Group object here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_group.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir I will check this!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out workbench.developerforce.com which lets you write SOQL queries and run them against SF objects.

So write your query there first, then replicate in Python

[image]

Comment: I will check this as well,does it require admin access etc for getting the workbench set up!